# How can I avoid duplicated functions using MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm building an application using ASP.NET Core, and I would like to avoid duplicated code, in the following situation. I'm using usermanager to get all users with a specific role, but I'm using the exact same function for three diferent controllers because I don't know how to reuse the function.

I've read about action filters, but I don't know how to adapt my code in this situation.

Example first controller:

```
public class FirstController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> emails = await GetAdminEmails();
        ViewBag.Emails = emails;
    }

    private async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetAdminEmails()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> emails = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var email in _userManager.Users.ToList())
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email.Email);
            var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                if (role == "Admin")
                {
                    emails.Add(email.Email, email.Id);
                }
            }
        }

        return emails;
    }
}
```

Second controller

```
public class SecondController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> emails = await GetAdminEmails();
        ViewBag.Emails = emails;
    }

    private async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetAdminEmails()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> emails = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var email in _userManager.Users.ToList())
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email.Email);
            var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                if (role == "Admin")
                {
                    emails.Add(email.Email, email.Id);
                }
            }
        }

        return emails;
    }
}
```

Third controller

```
public class ThirdController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> emails = await GetAdminEmails();
        ViewBag.Emails = emails;
    }

    private async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetAdminEmails()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> emails = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var email in _userManager.Users.ToList())
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email.Email);
            var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                if (role == "Admin")
                {
                    emails.Add(email.Email, email.Id);
                }
            }
        }

        return emails;
    }
}
```

Comment: Move the function into a separate class, then have each controller use that class?

Comment: You can introduce a `base` class (Inherited from `Controller`) and implement `GetAdminEmails` in that. All 3 controllers can inherit from new base class.

Comment: I agree with Amy, but you could also create an extension method for the UserManager<ApplicationUser> class that returns the dictionary of emails.  Whether the method is an extension or not, it should be in a separate class from all 3 controllers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put `GetAdminEmails` in a separate class like this:

```
public interface IEmailManager
{
    public Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetAdminEmails(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager);
}
```

Implement the interface

```
public class EmailManager : IEmailManager
{
    public async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetAdminEmails(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> emails = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var email in userManager.Users.ToList())
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email.Email);
            var roles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                if (role == "Admin")
                {
                    emails.Add(email.Email, email.Id);
                }
            }
        }

        return emails;
    }
}
```

First Controller

```
public class FirstController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
    private readonly IEmailManager emailManager;

    public FirstController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IEmailManager emailManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.emailManager = emailManager;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index() =>
        ViewBag.Emails = await this.emailManager.GetAdminEmails(userManager);
}
```

Second Controller

```
public class SecondController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
    private readonly IEmailManager emailManager;

    public SecondController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IEmailManager emailManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.emailManager = emailManager;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index() =>
        ViewBag.Emails = await this.emailManager.GetAdminEmails(userManager);
}
```

Comment: This assumes that an IoC container has been setup, but ultimately I believe this is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom base controller that has the common functionality (your GetAdminEmails method):

```
public class BaseController : Controller
```

and move the common method there.

Then, on each of the three controllers above change

```
public class xxxController : Controller
```

to

```
public class xxxController : BaseController
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good time to create a `UserService` class and add it to your services for it to be used in the controller through dependency Injection.

```c
class UserService : IUserService
{
    Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetAdminEmails()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Add it to the service provider in startup.cs

`services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>()`

then use it in any controllers

```cs
public class FirstController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    public FirstController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }
}
```

if you need access to `User` in `UserService`, just inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into your `UserService` through DI.